# Show each number separated after comma in php

Tags: php, sql, command-line

I have two tables

category

```
id | category
------
1  | One
2  | Two
```

etc

second one is

mp_photos

```
id|name|test|CategoryID
1 |name|test|1,2
```

So now i need to fetch data from mp_photos row CategoryID (1,2) every categoryid is seppareted by comma and link every number with Category name in first table

Comment: As you have found out, this is a difficult situation to deal with.  The `CategoryID` column should actually be a separate normalized table linking one category id to one id, multiple rows per `id`.

Comment: It is _highly advisable_ to change this schema if you have the opportunity to (if it isn't already in production under heavy use, for example).

Comment: If you cannot restructure your schema to be properly normalized, you are likely going to have to query the comma-separated value in PHP, `explode()` it, then query all the category names in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Best option would be to restructure your database and create another table with `id_mp_photos` and `id_category` and use joins.

If you cannot do it there are two options (both are slow):

1. use `explode()` in php
2. use MySQL function `FIND_IN_SET()`, for example:

   `SELECT mp_photos.name, mp_photos.test, category.category
    FROM mp_photos JOIN category ON FIND_IN_SET(category.id, mp_photos.CategoryID) > 0`

Comment: When i use explode() i got everything from that cell in one row, how i can sepparated every number and exclude ,

Comment: You can for example read `category` table to an array and then do `explode` on `CategoryID` field, iterate over category ids and use category name from array. (assuming `category` table is small - otherwise reading all rows into an array wouldn't be the best idea)